# Heroku - Read-only file system - /var/www?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment

I am trying to migrate the db and I am getting this error..

```
heroku rake db:migrate
(in /app)
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant RUBY
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
Read-only file system - /var/www
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:243:in `fu_mkdir'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:201:in `each'
/usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:201:in `mkdir_p'
/app/config/initializers/setup_shared_data.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load'
/app/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:147:in `load_with_new_constant_marking'
/app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `block in load_application_initializers'
/app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/app/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/app/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
```

How do i fix this or what can I do to dig in this deeper....

Answer (score 5):

It looks like line 6 of `/app/config/initializers/setup_shared_data.rb` is trying to create a directory on the local filesystem (that's what `mkdir` is).

This is not allowed on Heroku because the file system is read-only (except `/tmp`). See the documentation [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110810070802/http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) for more info on this limitation.

Add that line to your question and maybe I can offer a more specific answer.

Comment: link dead please provide missing informations if still recoverable

Comment: @GrecoJonathan I've updated the link to the original content on the wayback machine, but I'm not sure that it's relevant for modern Heroku stacks. A more recent discussion of the filesystem limitations can be found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Comment: it will be nice, if the content moves again to put here the relevant informations

Answer (score 1):

With regards to rdoctask being deprecated...consider adding:

```
`gem 'rdoc'`
```

to your Gemfile. Optionally, you can add rdoc/ to your .gitignore.

Another way would be to edit your Rakefile:

```
require 'rdoc/task'
RDoc::Task.new do |rdoc|
```

It would be helpful if you can post your Gemfile.

Answer (score -2):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWK73.png)[read/write][2]

heroku run bash -a yourapplication 
and change chmod 777 -R folder or chmod 777 -R file